# How to generate documentation of own code using pydoc?

Tags: python, pydoc

I need to generate documentation using Pydoc.
I already wrote some explanation using Docstrings like following example

```
def function():
    '''
    this function does something
    :return: returns nothing
    '''
```

Then I try to see my documentation via Windows PowerShell. Therefore I use

```
python -m pydoc myfile.py
```

But all I achieve is following error:

```
problem in myFile - IndexError: list index out of range
```

My script do need some more arguments, e.g.:

`python -m pydoc myfile.py argument1 argument2`

But then I receive following errors:

```
No Python Documentation found for myfile.
No Python Documentation found for argument1.
No Python Documentation found for argument2.
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with pydoc, but with the Python code you've written; the error

`problem in myFile - IndexError: list index out of range`

means that somewhere in your code, you're trying to access a list element by index.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist[0] # should yield "1"
mylist[1] # should yield "2"
mylist[2] # should yield "3"
```

but the index you're using is not valid.

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
mylist[3] # the index 3 is out of range for this list, so it will give you a IndexError
```

Make sure that all of the index values that you're using to access your list are between 0 and the length of your list minus one, and then run this at the command line:

`python -m pydoc myfile`

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about that.
My file needs some more arguments from command line (e.g. python myfile.py argument1 argument2)
How can I make that work? If I try to simply write it after my script the error switches to following:
No Python documentation found for 'myfile'
No Python documentation found for 'argument1'
No Python documentation found for 'argument2'

Comment: Pydoc wants a module name, not a file name. Try ```python -m pydoc myfile``` instead. I don't think you need to worry about the additional arguments, but let me know if it's still causing you problems.

Comment: You're absolutely right.
Pydoc only want's the module name but certainly I also need the arguments to show the documentation
So the working command line would be:
python -m pydoc myfile argument1 argument2